# Missing table name in from clause after upgrading to Rails 5.2

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I tried to upgrade a fairly huge project from Rails 5.1.4 to Rails 5.2 (also upgraded `mysql2` from 0.3.10 to 0.5.1) and I ran into an issue when using joins. Consider the following models:

```
class TermsVersionApproval < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :terms_version
end

class TermsVersion < ApplicationRecord
end
```

When I do a join it generates invalid sql by leaving out the table name after the `FROM` statement and generating `FROM INNER JOIN`:

```
TermsVersionApproval.joins(:terms_version).to_sql
=> SELECT `terms_version_approvals`.* FROM INNER JOIN `terms_versions` ON `terms_versions`.`id` = `terms_version_approvals`.`terms_version_id`
```

I tried to reproduce it with a fresh Rails 5.2 project, but there everything works. The project is pretty big, so I assume that there is some code deep down that collides with some new code in Rails 5.2 or the new mysql2 version. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find the bug so far.

Any idea on how to debug this? Or did anyone have a similar problem in the past? I also had to upgrade some other gems (list below), so maybe there where some bugs introduced.

Let me know if you need any other code, I'm unsure what parts may relate to the problem.

Gem upgrades:

- `rails 5.1.4 -> 5.2`
- `awesome_nested_se 3.1.3 -> 3.1.4`
- `devise 4.3.0 -> 4.4.3`
- `devise-token_authenticatable 1.0.0 -> 1.0.1`
- `mysql2 0.3.21 -> 0.5.1`
- `state_machines-activemodel 0.5.0 -> 0.5.1`
- (and some other minor changes that I assume have nothing to do with the error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue may reveal something to you:

https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/polyamorous/issues/34

After reading it, I would grep through your project for references to make_constraints, as it seems something has changed in 5.2 with regard to it that would lead to a similar error.

Or, if you see the polyamorous gem in your Gemfile.lock, problem solved, just update the gem as they fixed it in January.

Comment: This is just awesome, exactly that was the issue, thank you so much! polyamorous is used by ransack, I updated from 1.3.2 to 1.3.3, and everything works.